# Can the Developer's survey split out language choice for college BS or MS recipients?

Tags: feature-request, survey, languages, survey-2017, popularity

Colleges and universities want to know what skills lead to the best jobs so what programming languages should they teach? And how does that differ for those working on BS vs MS degrees? Can such information be part of the next Developer's Survey or deduced from the last?